# Empty then on promise

Tags: javascript, promise, es6-promise

During work, I stumbled upon this line inside our codebase (designed to run in the browser). Is there any effect in this line? It seems unnecessary to me, but before removing it, I want to be absolutely sure that I am not overlooking some quirky promise special behaviour that this line does.

```js
// Chain the finishPromise to our global finish chain.
this.finishPromise = this.finishPromise.then();
```

Next to that line, it is `await`ed some times, is initialized as `Promise.resolve()`, and never else overwritten as far as I can see.

Comment: What is the use of the `this.finishPromise` after that line? 

Can you add more details of the context around this?

Comment: I adjusted the question accordingly - it is initialized as resolved, awaited a few times, but that's it.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming this is a native JavaScript promise or anything else that's Promises/A+-compatible and doesn't have custom side-effects,¹ it's valid ([JS spec](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-promise.prototype.then), [Promises/A+ spec](https://promisesaplus.com/#the-then-method)) — which surprised me slightly — but useless and doesn't have any effect. You can safely remove it.

---

¹ *"...and doesn't have custom side-effects..."* The comment above it saying "Chain the finishPromise to our global finish chain" makes me wonder if this is a promise subclass (or worse, a monkey-patched version of the normal `Promise.prototype.then`) with some kind of side effect. But it could just as easily have been explaining something that was originally passed to `then` and has been subsequently removed...